# How to set highlight on QPushButton hovering

Tags: c++, qt

How can I highlight a `QPushButton` when the user hovers it with the mouse?

I want something like the Toolbox from GIMP (flat buttons, checkable, highlighted on hovering)

Comment: Sometimes, you just have to split your question into two and google `do something on QPushButton hovering` and `QPushButton highlight`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Double click on the .ui file of the project.
2. Right click on the button.
3. Left click on: 'Change styleSheet...'.
4. Add: `'QPushButton:hover { background-color: red; }` (where QPushButton is the class of the button) or something else. It is css code.
5. Click on 'Apply'.
6. Click on 'OK'.